# Raid on ICH9R chip set

Tags: raid

Hi Im looking at buyign this MB: 
   http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/ATOM/ICH9/X7SPE-HF-D525.cfm

Im wondering though if the chipset will support the raid configuration I need. Im looking to configure the following arrays:

raid array 1:
2 2TB Disks in Raid 0

raid array 2:
2 2TB Disks in Raid 0

raid array 3 (not actualy an array):
1 300GB Disk not in raid, to be used for OS and boot.

So in total there would be 5 drives and the board supports 6. so im good when it comes to connections. However I have herd some chip sets only support one raid array (volume). so either all drives are individual, or are in the array. I must have 2 sperate raid arrays independent of each other, and a 5th drive not in any array.

Anybody  know if this setup will work?

Thanks,
-Stewart

Comment: This website is dedicated to programming. There are two other sites in the stackoverflow family you might try, serverfault.com and superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 RAID volumes on that MB:

Source:

> Hi Joe
>
> You can have up to two RAID volumes.
>
> Cheers
>
> Ning Ning Application Engineer
>
> Super Micro Computer B.V. Het
>   Sterrenbeeld 28 5215 ML,
>   's‑Hertogenbosch The Netherlands
>   Tel: +31(0)73‑6400390 Ext.132 Fax: +31(0)73‑6416525
>    www.supermicro.com